# "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING" Thrown in previously working code when used with remote server. Why?

Tags: php, mysql

This was working fine while I was testing it locally, but after trying to use a remote mysql server its started throwing errors. The main one I cant figure out being,

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in G:\wamp\www\OnlineBank\bank.php on line 92"

```
              $query = "SELECT user_name FROM Customers";
              $result = mysql_query($query);
(--> line 92) while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die mysql_error())
              {
                  if ($username == $row['user_name'])
                  {
                       echo "<script>alert('User name is taken')</script>";
                       ...
                  }
```

as far as i'm aware that error is usually thrown for unescaped quotes and stuff, I just can't figure out why its happening here, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think `die()` is a function in PHP

Comment: @Rafe No, it's a language construct, but you still hit on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

That particular parse error stems from the fact that you need to surround arguments to `die` in parentheses:

```
or die(mysql_error())
```

The other answers hit on other points that may be wrong in your code though.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this was ever working; the error is caused by the `or die mysql_error()` within the while-condition.
Move that to the line above, like

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die mysql_error();
```

There will be no (mysql related) errors when using mysql_fetch_array(), so the check is pointless there anyway.

If you insist on keeping it in the while-condition you have to use parentheses -> `die( mysql_error() )`

Comment: Firstly, this was working. I originall didn't have the 'or die mysql_error()' in the code and only added it in an attempt to fix the errors. Though it seems I did in the wrong place. Either way, moving it to the line above simply makes the error report as being in the line above. and removing it completely throws a 'Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in G:\wamp\www\OnlineBank\bank.php on line 176', Line 176 being another ' while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))' line

Comment: You cannot say that it worked and than say that you changed something; the code you showed to use never worked, never could. Well, changing something made it work no more. Anyway, the Warning is thrown because your query does not return a result. Though the warning is thrown with mysql_fetch_array() it is caused by mysql_query(), so you should catch it there.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die mysql_error())
```

Firstly, you do not need to call `mysql_error()` in this situation. All you have to do is to call it if `mysql_query()` returns `FALSE`:

```
$query = "SELECT user_name FROM Customers";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if( $result==false ){
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Furthermore, `mysql_fetch_array()` returns `FALSE` every time it reaches the end of set of elements retrieved from MySQL. So, in common way, you have no need to use `or die mysql_error()` in this loop.